# Phonegap/Cordova jQuery $.get not working in iOS simulator

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap

I have `<access origin="*" allows-arbitrary-loads.../>` in my config.xml, I have allowed arbitrary loads in my info.plist, and the jQuery is syntactically correct and works, but not as part of the Xcode project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add the required settings to the server? The server also needs to be set up with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: The request succeeds elsewhere. It only fails on iOS.